# Сгруппировать список слов по частям речи и сохранить в отдельные файлы

Tags: python, pymorphy2

```
dict = open('C:\\Users\\nvasi\\Desktop\\slovar.txt',"r", encoding="utf-8").readlines() # словарь
word = dict[0].rstrip()           # слово. 0 - это строка. Каждое слово с новой строки
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer() # морфологический анализатор
p = morph.parse(word)[0]  
print(p.tag)                      # возвращает "INFN,impf,tran", где "INFN" - это часть речи
```

Нужно каждую строку (от `0` до `41469`) определить соответствующий словарь частей речи, 
т.е если в переменной `p.tag` - `INFN`, .. то записывать его в `INFN.txt`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Атрибут `.tag` возвращает объект `pymorphy2.tagset.OpencorporaTag`, который содержит много дополнительной информации:

```
In [266]: tag = morph.parse("слово")[0].tag

In [267]: tag
Out[267]: OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,neut sing,nomn')

In [268]: type(tag)
Out[268]: pymorphy2.tagset.OpencorporaTag

In [269]: tag.
               tag.ANIMACY                     tag.GENDERS                     tag.NUMBERS                     tag.RARE_CASES                  tag.add_grammemes_to_known
               tag.ASPECTS                     tag.INVOLVEMENT                 tag.PARTS_OF_SPEECH             tag.TENSES                      tag.animacy
               tag.CASES                       tag.KNOWN_GRAMMEMES             tag.PERSONS                     tag.TRANSITIVITY                tag.aspect                      >
               tag.FORMAT                      tag.MOODS                       tag.POS                         tag.VOICES                      tag.case
```

Как уже сказал @insolor в своем ответе, можно воспользоваться атрибутом `tag.POS` (Part Of Speach), чтобы получить наименование части речи в виде строки.

---

Пример:

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import groupby
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer

infile = Path(r"C:\Temp\slovar.txt")
words = infile.read_text(encoding="utf-8").splitlines()
print(words)
#['каждый', 'охотник', 'желает', 'знать', 'где', 'сидит', 'фазан']

morph = MorphAnalyzer()

items = [(str(morph.parse(w)[0].tag.POS), w) for w in words]

print(items)
#[('ADJF', 'каждый'), ('NOUN', 'охотник'), ('VERB', 'желает'), ('INFN', 'знать'), ('ADVB', 'где'), ('VERB', 'сидит'), ('NOUN', 'фазан')]

for g, it in groupby(sorted(items), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    otufile = infile.parent / f"{g}.txt"
    otufile.write_text("\n".join([word for pos, word in it]),
                       encoding="utf-8")
```

Результат:

*NOUN.txt:*

```
охотник
фазан
```

*VERB.txt:*

```
желает
сидит
```

...

Comment: Выходит ошибка TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'TypedGrammeme'

Comment: @НиколайВасиленков, исправил ответ - теперь должен создаваться один дополнительный файл `None.txt` со всеми "словами" для которых pymorphy2 не смог определить часть речи

Comment: Спасибо больщое :)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше брать не `p.tag`, а `p.tag.POS` (POS - Part of speech, т.е. часть речи) - это будет готовая строка с названием части речи (см. [Руководство пользователя/работа с тегами](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/guide.html#id4)). Добавляете в конце `.txt` - получите имя файла. Открываете файл с этим именем на запись, пишете туда что вам нужно.